# Por que no me muestra nada en el arcivho php pero en Mysql si?

Tags: php

Lo hago de esa forma para mostrar todos los productos con la letra A pero solo me muestra una ventana en blanco, o si le hago con un WHERE pk_familia IN (7) me sigue sin mostrar nada pero si en cambio pongo el 1 si muestra pero ciertos numeros no me los muestra como le puedo hacer e tratado en diferentes situaciones pero nada solo me muestra una ventana en blanco ya le aumente la memoria al php.in y sigue sin funcionar

```html
/*
* Created by Belal Khan
* website: www.simplifiedcoding.net 
* Retrieve Data From MySQL Database in Android
*/

//database constants
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'erpbd1_refagu03');

//connecting to database and getting the connection object
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//Checking if any error occured while connecting
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

//creating a query
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cat_articulos WHERE descripcion LIKE '%A%' ORDER BY descripcion ASC");

//executing the query 
$stmt->execute();

//binding results to the query 
$stmt->bind_result($pk_articulo, $pk_familia, $descripcion, $marca, $prec_costo);

$products = array();

//traversing through all the result 
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['pk_articulo'] = $pk_articulo; 
    $temp['pk_familia'] = $pk_familia; 
    $temp['descripcion'] = $descripcion; 
    $temp['marca'] = $marca; 
    $temp['prec_costo'] = $prec_costo; 
    array_push($products, $temp);
}

//displaying the result in json format 
echo json_encode($products);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que tiene que ver tu explicacion con tu codigo? en ninguna parte de tu codigo tenes WHERE pk_familia IN (7).. que es ese 7? que datos tiene la base de datos? Estas seguro que te conectas a la misma base?

Comment: Tambien deberias agregar la estructura de tu tabla.

Comment: Has un top 100 a tu select y cuéntanos qué es lo que pasa?

Comment: gracias ya lo resolvi lo que paso es que algunos numeros estan erroneos en la BD y no me los muestra pero exclullendo esos ya me mostro